# self check database

Tags: php, sql

hello its there a php script that can check if its a new id inside mysql and contact me over email if new id detected ?

Comment: it's called a trigger (if MySQL) and cron. put those 2 together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are approaching the problem from the wrong perspective and over complicating it. How do the ID's get into the database? You should go to that point in the code and log it and/or notify yourself at that point. For example, if you want to be notified each time a user signs up to your site, upon a successful sign up, send yourself a mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cron job to do that for you

Comment: that "comment" has already been said, in "comments" which I might add, only covered 50% of the question and no code examples to boot.

Comment: I'm not able to comment yet and I didn't see your comment when sumbitting

Comment: you should at the very least, provide the OP with code examples.

Comment: well someone ^ is the reason for that

Comment: that isn't my dv, btw.

Comment: it's alright I know who it is. They dv all my post

Comment: I know the feeling. I've someone doing that to me too.

Comment: Thank you all for you`r support but, because i have little knowledge about php to start building CRON i am not sure its necessary right now , good i know what to look for wen the time comes  I have ask for this because i was thinking will be something simple whit just couple more command than what i  already known but its not. For now number one priority its to protect against, sql injection (baby hackers) .Thank you again all. If you are interested in what my project its ! A live demo hear abcd 123 http://transylvanyanorthampton.com/wfuk/index.html